# Compare two CSV files and create new CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have two CSV files without any header. I want to compare two CSV files and create a new CSV file with the compared data.

This is my Python script:

```
f = open('comp.csv', 'r')
g = open('comp2.csv', 'r')
line = 0

print('Differences Found')

while True:
    lineF = f.readline().strip()
    lineG = g.readline().strip()
    line += 1

    if (lineF or lineG):
        if (lineF != lineG):
            print("Line %d (%s vs %s)" % (line, lineF, lineG))
    else:
        f.close()
        g.close()
        break
```

Help me to get out of this.

Comment: What is the issue?  What error or bad behavior are you getting.  If you can give two sample csv files and the results your program gives.

Comment: Get out of *what*?

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
h = open('diffs.csv', 'w')
        ...
            print("Line %d (%s vs %s)" % (line, lineF, lineG))
            h.write("Line %d (%s vs %s)\n" % (line, lineF, lineG))
        ...
        h.close()
        break
```

but I wouldn't recommend it.

## style nit 1: with open...

Prefer

```
with open('diffs.csv', 'w') as h:
    ...
    h.write( ... )
    ...
```

over having to remember to do an explicit `h.close()`.

## style nit 2: import csv

Let me introduce you to a very helpful library:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Start with `f = csv.reader(open('comp.csv'))` and similar.
And then you can compare one row with another,
but you might prefer to compare specific elements.
Perhaps `row_f[0] == row_g[0]` always,
and differences in element `[1]` or `[2]` are of greatest interest.

The output formatting would be improved using

```
with csv.writer(open('diffs.csv', 'w')) as h_sheet:
            ...
            h_sheet.writerow((line, lineF, lineG))
            ...
```